# Unverified smart contract call function without know abi ? can we find it from its website?

Tags: abi

I am new on this things sorry i will ask like a noob
I will give what i have and ask you
1- 0xmintcontract
2- 0xtoken
3- have access on website to mint
both unverified

So there is a website i am minting token from when i click i see 0x328432 example method number 0xmintcontact giving me example 100x 0xtoken when i do it from website it is working well and able to check its method and some other stuff on testnetbscscan really i tried many things i am not able to do it

Please can you give me some idea i am really new on this . I tried to get that calls from website frontend codes but i wasn't able to do it i tried some method call scripts i am doing something wrong i guess if you can help me i will be so appreciated

Thanks for helping

Have a great day

Comment: If it is a standard token you could use the ABI from a different token that provides the functionality.

Comment: it is not standart sir but some people able to do it idk how there is a way to do it but idk how

Comment: Unfortunately if you don't know the contract abi, and it is not an standard contract your only options is to reverse engineer the bytecode. You can try copying already executed transactions but you will never be sure what the contract is doing.

Comment: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x744ab00ade1daf63ecb0c29c97d266f9cc8ccd488d74443a8d073054b24ac66a

can you check this transaction sir is it possible to find its abi ? or make any script to do that transaction ? there is contract bytecode decompiled here

https://testnet.bscscan.com/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x3cc6fc1035465d5b238f04097df272fe9b60eb94

i want call that contract and mint that token 
https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0x06a0f0fa38ae42b7b3c8698e987862afa58e90d9

but i tried many scripts not work for me. i tried to make abi from decompiled script but still not work

Comment: Those contracts are unverified. Unless the creators publish the ABI or provide some documentation it will be quite complicated to make transactions.